# How do App Store Optimisation tools get their data?

Tags: ios-appstore

There are tools for iOS developers like Sensortower and MobiledevHQ that let app marketers analyse the App Store with regards to keyword and category rankings.

I assume the keyword rankings can be obtained by fetching the search result lists for each keyword.

But these tools also provide search volume statistics. Does any one know how they get the data? For instance, how do they know that keyword X is searched 3 times as often as keyword Y?

Comment: I'm not sure this is even on-topic for the site. Could you perhaps edit this to explain a little what practical problem you are looking to solve? This looks more like customer support for a company other than Apple and not about using an apple product / service.

Comment: I am asking out of curiosity and understanding of how the App Store works. Is there a better stackexchange site to ask this kind of question?

Comment: If the question is does apple have an API or sell the data - it's on topic here and will have a short answer. (no) If you are trying to make decisions as a developer - maybe SO? I'm hesitant to suggest a site without knowing if you have a practical question other than speculation on internal procedures of a class of businesses. Keep in mind - http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - and maybe [chat] to clear up what you are trying to do...